# ZeroDivisionError: division by zero. What needs to be changed

Tags: python

```
def get_success_rate(statistics: str) -> int:
    count = 0
    for i in statistics:
        if statistics == '':
            return 0
        if i == '1':
            count += 1
    res = count / len(statistics) * 100
    return round(res)


print(get_success_rate("11100"))  # 60
print(get_success_rate("1100"))  # 50
print(get_success_rate("000000"))  # 0
print(get_success_rate("11111"))  # 100
print(get_success_rate(""))  # 0
```

```
60
50
0
100
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\CHERHOBNK\Folder - 1\draft.py", line 807, in <module>
    print(get_success_rate(""))  # 0
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\CHERHOBNK\Folder - 1\draft.py", line 799, in get_success_rate
    res = count / len(statistics) * 100
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: Move the check for `statistics == ''` before the loop

Comment: Just check `if statistics == ''`. As it is you loop over `statistics`, but if it's empty the loop will iterate zero times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of your function is not sound. Guessing from the code, you probably want to do the `if statistics == ''` clause *before* your iteration, `for i in statistics`. Then you'll no longer have the division by zero error of your function.

the problem with your current code, is that the iteration doesn't happen when statistics == '', there's nothing to iterate over. And then the call is made to `res = count / len(statistics) * 100`, and as `len("")` equals zero, that's giving you the division by zero error

Answer (score 2):

Move the empty string check outside the loop:

```
def get_success_rate(statistics: str) -> int:
    if statistics == '':
        return 0
    count = 0
    for i in statistics:
        if i == '1':
            count += 1
    res = count / len(statistics) * 100
    return round(res)
```

If string is empty the loop will not be executed so the check will actually be skipped.